# Selecting a disabled form in Python

Tags: python, mechanize, python-2.6, mechanize-python

I've been trying to select a form which has a "disabled" attribute in the button and python keep giving error saying:

```
AttributeError: control 'None' is disabled
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://test.com" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input name="abc" type="hidden" value="def">
<input type="hidden" name="ghi" value="jkl">
<button disabled></button>
</form>
```

The code I use:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

After I select it, I get the above error, any way I can remove that "disabled" attribute from the form by editing the html within the mechanize or any other way around it?

Answer (score -2):

I saw that the mechanize source code tries to assign a value of `""` to the disabled button in class SubmitControl(_form.py:2336) which causes the issue:

```
if self.value is None: self.value = ""
```

Maybe this is a bug in mechanize?

I tried a hack for now and it seems to be working, but I don't know the full consequences of this:

```
if self.value is None and self.disabled==False: self.value = ""
```

Comment: Still, Don't post comments as answers. People will downvote and you will go further away from the rep needed to comment. Invest some time, Earn more rep, Then comment. 50 rep is not that far away, trust me.